# How to check if a cell is empty in a range variable?

Tags: excel, vba

Why does the result in cell A1 returns "2" even if there is no values in either of the B1 to B3 cells?

Sub CheckEmpty()

```
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("$B$1:$B$3")
Debug.Print rng.Address

If IsEmpty(Range(rng.Address)) Then
    Range("A1").Value = "1"
    Else
    Range("A1").Value = "2"
End If
```

End Sub

I've tried including values in either cell b1, b2 or b3 but they results returns 0 even if the cells were blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `WorksheetFunction.CountA()` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.counta) function

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
    Range("A1").Value = "1"
Else
    Range("A1").Value = "2"
End If
```